# android : get current position of videos in webview

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming

I am playing youtube videos in webview .In my app i have overridden the ontouch of webview. SO when user clicks on webview playing video, it opens another webview which is full screen . Now  here the video is starting from the beginning. Instead of that is there a way to get the current postion of the video and to start playing from that point in the new webview. 
ie i am looking for something equivalent to getCurrentposition and seekto in a videoview.

Please let me know if this is possible or is there any work around.

Thank you

Comment: @preetha - I am also looking for the same, did you find any solution or work around?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before and I warn you that things might get messy in future!
Anyways, take a look at "JavaScriptInterface" for webview in android. here is a [link](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-javascriptinterface-tutorial.html)

Also take a look at [google's youtube player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

There is Android youtube player as well as players using javascript/iframe etc.